# Laravel Pass Array Parameters to Filter

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-filters

I need to pass an array to a filter in my controller's constructor. The problem is that to pass parameters to a filter you do:

```
$this->beforeFilter('filterName:param1,param2');
```

And to pass an array, I need to `json_encode` which makes the array as a string separated by comma. So the following command:

```
$array = ['this', 'that', 'other'];
$this->beforeFilter('filterName:' . json_encode($array));
// The above line basically becomes:
// $this->beforeFilter('filterName:["this","that","other"]');
```

is passed to my filter as:

```
Route::filter('filterName', function($route, $request, $param1, $param2, $param3)
{
    // $param1 is ["this"
    // $param2 is "that"
    // $param3 is "other"]
});
```

Since I don't know how big my array is, I can't reconstruct the array. What can I do?

**Update**

One thing I could so is

```
Route::filter('filterName', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    $params = array_except(func_get_args(), array(0, 1));
    if(count($params) > 3) {
        $params = json_decode(implode(",", $params));

        // Now use $params
    }
});
```

This works fine for an array. but if I pass an embedded array, the result becomes an `stdObject`, which is okay but I don't like the fact that I passed an array, and got an object.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use `json_encode()` instead of just imploding the array and then writing `$this->beforeFilter("filterName: $array);`